# Storing a Complex Object in Session State

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

I have a separate class under my App_Code folder (.NET project) called "StateBag.cs"

using System;
using System.Text;

```
[Serializable()]
public class MyStateBag
{
    public MyStateBag(){}
    private string _MemberID = string.Empty;
    public string MemberID
    {
        get { return _MemberID; }
        set { _MemberID = value; }
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to update the MemberID value from any page of my web project.

example:-

Default.aspx.cs:-

```
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public StateBag MyStateBag
    {
        get { return (StateBag)Session["MyStateBag"]; }
        set { Session["MyStateBag"] = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyStateBag = (StateBag)Session["MyStateBag"];
    }

    .... }
```

On my Default.aspx.cs Page I am trying to set the value of memberID into MyStateBag:-

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStateBag"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStateBag"] = new StateBag();
        }
        ((StateBag)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStateBag"]).MemberID = memID;
```

However I get a conflict:-
**'System.Web.UI.StateBag' does not contain a definition for 'MemberID' and no extension method 'MemberID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.StateBag' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Do I have to reference something on my Default.aspx.cs page that I am missing out on??

and how can i access it back...say I am on a different page,"About.aspx.cs".

I want to be able to say :-`memberinfo = StateBag["MemberID"]`

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Nit: View State is *not* Session State and is [almost always] tied to a *specific* page (or rather, it exists in the generated HTML and while reconstituted server-side). To persist state *across* different pages, you may be interested in Session State (since Session is used, why is this tagged ViewState?), Cookies, or encoding the state into the Page URI.

Comment: excellent! so examples code please?

Comment: I tried this but my value is not being saved:-
//HttpContext.Current.Session["memID"] = memID;
            //string memberinfo = string.Empty;
            //memberinfo = HttpContext.Current.Session["memID"].ToString();

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Web Site "project" (File->New Web Site, or Add->New Web Site), or an ASP.NET Web Application Project (File->New Project or Add->New Project)? It makes a difference as far as code files go.

Comment: @JohnSaunders its a webapplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything you save to the Session object will stay with that user as they travel around your site.  So on Default.aspx.cs you might have something like:

```
//Make sure there is an object saved for this user
if(Session["StateBag"] == null)
   Session["StateBag"] = new StateBag();

//Set what you need
((StateBag)Session["StateBag"]).MemberID = 1234;
```

Then on another page you can access it the same way

```
//Make sure there is an object saved for this user
if(Session["StateBag"] == null)
   Session["StateBag"] = new StateBag();

//Get what you need
int memberID = ((StateBag)Session["StateBag"]).MemberID
```

Comment: I bet your StateBag class that you defined is getting confused with the System.Web.UI.StateBag class.  Try renaming your StateBag to something else that's unique.

Comment: So I changed StateBag.cs to MyStateBag.cs and the rest of the code now refers to MyStateBag.cs. Still the same conflict. I updated my code if you would kindly take a look again.

Comment: You have to cast it to a MyStateBag, not StateBag cause StateBag doesn't have a MemberID property.

Comment: ((StateBag)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStateBag"]).MemberID = memID; needs to be ((MyStateBag)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyStateBag"]).MemberID = memID;

Comment: Thanks Lee, Now I get a new error that says: _Default.MyStateBag' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Comment: So I made a couple of mistakes, as Lee said I need to reference MyStateBag instead of StateBag through all my Default.aspx.cs code.

Also, the way I solved the type problem, was right clicked MyStateBag.cs class and set the property from content to compile. Since this is an object, it must be pre-compiled rather than treated as a content.